# Main domain htaccess is also redirecting addon domain from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a main domain that is https site and the addon domain doesn't needs to be https. But due to htaccess now addon domain is also redirecting to https.

This is the code I have in htaccess of main domain-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `RewriteCond` to restrict first `http -> https` rule to a particular domain only:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.